# Regex: stripping multi-line comments but maintaining a line break & Single line comments at start of new line

Tags: python, regex

The input next fle is as follows

```
int 1; //integer
//float 1; //floating point number
int m; //integer
/*if a==b
begin*/
print 23 /* 1, 2, 3*/
end
float/* ty;
int yu;*/
```

Expected output is as follows

```
int 1; //integer
int m; //integer
print 23 
end
float
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a two step replacement which seems to work:

```py
inp = """int 1; //integer
//float 1; //floating point number
int m; //integer
/*if a==b
begin*/
print 23 /* 1, 2, 3*/
end
float/* ty;
int yu;*/"""

output = re.sub(r'^\s*//.*?\n', '', inp, flags=re.M)
output = re.sub(r'\n?/\*.*?\*/(\n?)', r'\1', output, flags=re.M|re.S)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
int 1; //integer
int m; //integer
print 23 
end
float
```

The first call to `re.sub` removes all lines which start with a `//` comment.  The second call to `re.sub` removes the C-style `/* */` comments.  It works by trying to match a newline both before and after the comment itself.  Then, it replaces with as much as only a single newline, assuming one followed the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert matches of the following to empty strings.

```
\/\/.*\r?\n|\/\/.*|^\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/\r?\n|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gd5ah2/1)

Note the second alternation element must follow the first and the fourth alternation element must follow the  third.

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?m)       # set multiline flag 
  ^\/\/    # match '//' at beginning of line
  .*\r?\n  # match 0+ chars other than line
           # terminators then match line terminator
|          # or
  \/\/.*   # match '//'
  .*       # match the remainder of the line
|          # or
  ^\/\*    # match '/*' at the beginning of a line
  [\s\S]*? # match 0+ characters including line
           # terminators, lazily
  \*\/     # match '*/'
  \r?\n    # match line terminators
|          # or
  \*\/     # match '*/'
  [\s\S]*? # match 0+ characters including line
           # terminators, lazily
  \*\/     # match '*/'
```